# Are there any tricks to set in css inheritance from another object or rule?

Tags: css

I'm looking for some trick(s) to make style inherited from another object/class/id. Simple trick: use classes, but are there another ways to specify style of another rule?

Sorry for explanation.. I'm looking for something like:
`.st1 {font-size:17pt;} .st2 {-moz/ms/webkit-extends: '.st1';}`?

Actually, I'm not really looking for it (because I use classes), just interested in.

Comment: :D I forgot what's the name of css ..'rule' (?). e.g. `body {margin:0;}`

Comment: If you don't want to use something like LESS, you can just give your elements two classes. `<whatever class="st1 st2">` And make sure that `.st2` is declared after `.st1` in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than searching for tricks, You are looking for CSS extension libraries like

- [SASS library](http://sass-lang.com/)
- [LESS library](http://lesscss.org/)

They do not exactly give a way to do it like you want, but provide even better one. Like

```
.st1 {font-size:17pt;} 
.st2 {
    .st1;
}
```

When the website is launched, these style declarations are compiled and optimized into a  valid CSS document.

Comment: Interesting.. LESS looks better than SASS. :)

Comment: How does it work? Parsing, after that adding obj.style.X=$style?

Comment: @Krylovech, I have edit my answer. To use it, just define the class to your element like `<div class="st2">` the styles of st1 will automatically be applied to it.

Comment: I have asked about how does it work? :) JavaScript parses files `rel="stylesheet/less"`, after - logical adding styles to objects?

Comment: @Krylovech, I told you, It will be compiled into a valid css document, when it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

CSS inheritance relays on the DOM structure, so unless the involved elements are having a descendant / ancestor relationship, no, CSS offers no such functionality.

you can, regardless, use libraries like [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) to implement template-like placeholders for property values, thereby turning your CSS into a dynamic stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, no

But if I understand you right:

- you have a *class X*
- then you want *class Y* to have everything of *class X* plus additional
  overwriting/new content?

I think you can try JavaScript to find every object with *class Y* and prepend the *class X*

Something like:

```
//disclaimer: I haven't tested it
var objs=document.getElementsByTagName('*');//getElementsByClassName, not very crossbrowser

for(var i=0,len=objs.length;i<len;i++){
    var temp=objs[i].className;
    if((" "+temp+" ").indexOf(" classY ")==-1){//spaces are important
        objs[i].className="classX "+temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: "not wery crossbrowser" - only because of IE < [9 version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname). :)
But thans for the function.

Comment: By the way, how to add to nodes my personal function? I wrote something, but how to declare it? e.g. `node.myFunc(myP);` or `document.getElementById('id').myFunc(myP);`

Comment: @Krylovech there are two options, pass a string with the id: `myFunc("id")`+inside the func use `document.getElementById(parameter1)`, or pass an object `myFunc(document.getElementById("id"))`+inside the func you work with the object at `parameter1`